# Missing usr/bin binaries in venv?

Tags: python, path, pycharm

When I am executing "os.system('ls /usr/bin')" from PyCharm with venv (and without) I miss some binaries that would show up when executing previous command from my "normal" terminal.
Seems to be a problem with my PyCharm-Environment...?

Comment: On Windows you do not have `ls` by default. And on many systems you may not have /usr/bin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm was installed as Flatpak, changing to snap package fixed the issue